# Different ways to pass request to Macro

Tags: macros, haxe, hexmachina

Macro can get a request by injection from payloads or directly from the dispatcher. But what if I need to use both ways of passing requests to same Macro? If it contains @Inject flag, and request is passed directly from dispatcher, I get an error about "missing mapping to inject into property".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to have the possibility to pass a request to your `Macro` sometimes through a payload, and sometimes without. And in the second case without making injection failing.

To achieve that, you can annotate your property with: `@Optional(true)`
This way, if the mapping is not available, the injector won't cry.

As you can guess, any injection with `Optional` annotation won't throw any error if the corresponding mapping is missing during injection process, because that way, injection becomes optional.

You can check an example [here](https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexInject/blob/master/test/hex/di/mock/injectees/OptionalClassInjectee.hx)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see your example, but when you want to pass a payload as an injected dependency, then it should be passed in the following way:

```
dispatcher.dispatch( MyMessage.MESSAGE, [myRequest, new ExecutionPayload(myPayload, MyPayload)] )
```

So the point is that you need to use the [hex.control.payload.ExecutionPayload](https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexCore/blob/master/src/hex/control/payload/ExecutionPayload.hx) class as a second argument of the dispatch. But i'm curious why don't you unify the two into one Request.